# Swift - Reading different types of values from a dictionary

Tags: swift, string, dictionary

Presently the code that I have is reading all the values as String. However at times when an integer or decimal values are present, it gets read as nil.

***Present code:***

```
let fieldName = String(arr[0])
var res = dict[fieldName.uppercased()] as? String
if res == nil {
   res = dict[fieldName.lowercased()] as? String
}
url = url.replacingOccurrences(of: testString, with: res?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharSet) ?? "")
```

There are times when "dict[fieldName.uppercased()]" returns value such as 3 or 40.4, but value in my res object is nil since I am expecting a string.

How can I get read different types of values and update the occurrences in my url?

***Code that I tried:***

```
let fieldName = String(arr[0])
var res = dict[fieldName.uppercased()] as? AnyObject
if res == nil {
   res = dict[fieldName.lowercased()] as? AnyObject
}
url = url.replacingOccurrences(of: testString, with: res?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharSet) ?? "")
```

With this I am getting errors while replacing the occurrences since "addingPercentEncoding" only works on String.

So I check the class of res object and if it is not String, I try doing the below, but getting error since res is of type AnyObject and if that's not present, I try to replace it with empty string.

```
url = url.replacingOccurrences(of: testString, with: res ?? "" as String)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with those integers and doubles? Convert them to string?

Comment: @Sweeper - Yeah I would either like to convert it to String or read it as it's own type and replace it in url. In the logic that I was trying, I wasn't trying to convert it to String, but reading it as is and was trying to replace it in URL.

Answer (score 1):

There is a common type of `String`, `Int` and `Double`: `CustomStringConvertible`

Conditional downcast the value to `CustomStringConvertible` and get a string with String Interpolation

```
let fieldName = String(arr[0])
if let stringConvertible = dict[fieldName.uppercased()] as? CustomStringConvertible {
    url = url.replacingOccurrences(of: testString, with: "\(stringConvertible)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharSet
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian! I do like this solution which I short and sweet, but I guess I will have to checkout the class for individual values as for when values are of type Int or Decimal, I don't want to add percent encoding. This solution adds percent encoding to all types of values.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the "get the dictionary value" part and the "convert it to my desired type" part. And you should check the type of the value you got from the dictionary using `if let` statements.

```
let value = dict[fieldName.uppercased()] ?? dict[fieldName.lowercased()]

if let string = value as? String {
    url = url.replacingOccurrences(of: testString, with: string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharSet) ?? "")
} else if let double = value as? Double {
    url = url.replacingOccurrences(of: testString, with: "\(double)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharSet) ?? "")
} else if let integer = value as? Int {
    url = url.replacingOccurrences(of: testString, with: "\(integer)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharSet) ?? "")
} else {
    // value is nil, or is none of the types above. You decide what you want to do here
}
```

Comment: I am getting "Argument type 'String?' does not conform to expected type 'StringProtocol'" error in replaceOccurrences for all 3.